# Why SpringApplicationBuilder.run() use AtomicBoolean obj and then use synchronized, AtomicBoolean can't keep thread safe?

Tags: java, spring-boot, synchronized, atomic

I read SpringBoot source code in 1.5.X, but I found a problem in Class `SpringApplicationBuilder`, it is `run` method code:

```java
    /**
     * Create an application context (and its parent if specified) with the command line
     * args provided. The parent is run first with the same arguments if has not yet been
     * started.
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @return an application context created from the current state
     */
    public ConfigurableApplicationContext run(String... args) {
        if (this.running.get()) {
            // If already created we just return the existing context
            return this.context;
        }
        configureAsChildIfNecessary(args);
        if (this.running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            synchronized (this.running) {
                // If not already running copy the sources over and then run.
                this.context = build().run(args);
            }
        }
        return this.context;
    }
```

as you see the `run` method use an AtomicBoolean field `running` to keep thread safe, compareAndSet is not thread safe? and why use synchronized ?

```
if (this.running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
    synchronized (this.running) {
        // thread safe
    }
}
```

```
if (this.running.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
    // not thread safe ?
}
```

what mean about this in `SpringApplicationBuilder.run()` ?